# Using Python sdk | Couchbase

Tags: python, database, couchbase

I am new with this, I was trying to connect to the couchbase bucket using python, just tried whatever given in the documentation.

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('username', 'password')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
bucket = cluster.open_bucket('bucket-name')
```

Replaced the IP, username, password, bucket name. But I am getting this error everytime I am trying to run this,

```
File "get_data_couche.py", line 6, in <module>
    bucket = cluster.open_bucket('jizo')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/couchbase/cluster.py", line 100, in open_bucket
    rv = self.bucket_class(str(connstr), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/couchbase/bucket.py", line 252, in __init__
    self._do_ctor_connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/couchbase/bucket.py", line 261, in _do_ctor_connect
    self._connect()
couchbase.exceptions._AuthError_0x2 (generated, catch AuthError): <RC=0x2[Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination], There was a problem while trying to send/receive your request over the network. This may be a result of a bad network or a misconfigured client or server, C Source=(src/bucket.c,793)>
```

Please help me with this, not able to find so much on internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that there is a networking issue (or you typo'd the credentials). I'm not a Python dev, but that's my guess. You can always try sdk-doctor: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/sdk-doctor

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will check it and if I will figure out any solution will update.

Comment: That's a pretty sad, worthless error message. They ought to be able to tell the difference between "bad password" and "unable to reach the server. "

Comment: That's true, I'm working in a periodic task that call the database each 5 minutes, when the db is no available, appears this message and obviously is not the user or password...